# Making image fit screen on click

Tags: javascript, php

I have an image that when clicked I wanna make fit screen. I'm currently using a simple IMG tag linking to the full image, but its not what i want.

```
 <div> <a href="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg" width="100%"></a> </div>
```

I want to make it fit screen (onclick), like it happens on the Tumblr or Twitter app on my iphone. Here's an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/RSJAv/) of the kind of effect I'm describing, but using an image.

I'm trying to make it happen in php or javascript, if possible, for Wordpress. Any help, including how you call this function, would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out bootstrap modals http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ They are super easy to use and look great on both mobile and desktop platforms.

Comment: [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) does something similar and is fairly flexible. I use it on a [project site](http://www.mymoroccanguide.com/en-GB/Gallery)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "make it fit screen" to mean the browser window entirely, you can do this!

```
/* Adding the class to the image itself */
$('div').click(function () {
   $(this).children('img').addClass('full-size');
});

/* Adding the class to the container div */
$('div').click(function () {
   $(this).addClass('full-size');
});

/* CSS */
.full-size {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: fixed;
}
```